# How to change the function a random forest uses to make decisions from individual trees?

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, random-forest, ensemble-learning

Random Forests use '*a multitude of decision trees at training time and outputting the class that is the mode of the classes (classification) of the individual trees*'.

Is there a way to, instead of using the class that is the mode, run another random forest on the outputs produced by the original trees?

Bonus question: is there a reason why this is a bad idea? (as I'm sure people will have thought of this before)

Comment: > Is there a way to, instead of using the class that is the mode, run another random forest on the resulting trees? 

I don't understand what you mean by "running" a random forest "on" decision trees.

Comment: @ogrisel op wants to use the outputs of each of the individual classifiers as features to train a new classifier. Bagging an already-bagged algorithm often actually works.

Comment: Attempted to make the question clearer, thanks for the comments

Comment: Using the leaf location of the predictions as feature for a second level classifier can be useful, e.g. a linear model such as logistic regression: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ogrisel/notebooks/blob/master/sklearn_demos/Income%20classification.ipynb#Using-the-boosted-trees-to-extract-features-for-a-Logistic-Regression-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the individual decision trees in the `estimators_` attribute of a fitted random forest instance.

You can even re-sample that attribute (it's just a Python list of decision tree objects) to add or remove trees and see the impact on the quality of the prediction of the resulting forest.

Answer (score 0):

I assume is just a performance option, your idea sounds fine, but without better "randomness" but probably slower on being computed.